# How to add multiple columns in R with different condition for each column?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

Here is my data set. I would like to add `5`  new columns to `mydata` with `5` different conditions.

```
mydata=data.frame(sub=rep(c(1:4),c(3,4,5,5)),t=c(1:3,1:4,1:5,1:5),
                      y.val=c(10,20,13,
                          5,7,8,0,
                          45,17,25,12,10,
                          40,0,0,5,8))
mydata
   sub t y.val
1    1 1    10
2    1 2    20
3    1 3    13
4    2 1     5
5    2 2     7
6    2 3     8
7    2 4     0
8    3 1    45
9    3 2    17
10   3 3    25
11   3 4    12
12   3 5    10
13   4 1    40
14   4 2     0
15   4 3     0
16   4 4     5
17   4 5     8
```

I would like to add the following `5 (max of 't' column)` columns as

```
mydata$It1=ifelse(mydata$t==1 & mydata$y.val>0,1,0)
mydata$It2=ifelse(mydata$t==2 & mydata$y.val>0,1,0)
mydata$It3=ifelse(mydata$t==3 & mydata$y.val>0,1,0)
mydata$It4=ifelse(mydata$t==4 & mydata$y.val>0,1,0)
mydata$It5=ifelse(mydata$t==5 & mydata$y.val>0,1,0)
```

Here is the expected outcome.

```
> mydata
   sub t y.val It1 It2 It3 It4 It5
1    1 1    10   1   0   0   0   0
2    1 2    20   0   1   0   0   0
3    1 3    13   0   0   1   0   0
4    2 1     5   1   0   0   0   0
5    2 2     7   0   1   0   0   0
6    2 3     8   0   0   1   0   0
7    2 4     0   0   0   0   0   0
8    3 1    45   1   0   0   0   0
9    3 2    17   0   1   0   0   0
10   3 3    25   0   0   1   0   0
11   3 4    12   0   0   0   1   0
12   3 5    10   0   0   0   0   1
13   4 1    40   1   0   0   0   0
14   4 2     0   0   0   0   0   0
15   4 3     0   0   0   0   0   0
16   4 4     5   0   0   0   1   0
17   4 5     8   0   0   0   0   1
```

I appreciate your help if it can be written as a function using for loop or any other technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sapply`/`lapply`

```
n <- seq_len(5)
mydata[paste0("It", n)] <- +(sapply(n, function(x) mydata$t==x & mydata$y.val>0))
mydata

#   sub t y.val It1 It2 It3 It4 It5
#1    1 1    10   1   0   0   0   0
#2    1 2    20   0   1   0   0   0
#3    1 3    13   0   0   1   0   0
#4    2 1     5   1   0   0   0   0
#5    2 2     7   0   1   0   0   0
#6    2 3     8   0   0   1   0   0
#7    2 4     0   0   0   0   0   0
#8    3 1    45   1   0   0   0   0
#9    3 2    17   0   1   0   0   0
#10   3 3    25   0   0   1   0   0
#11   3 4    12   0   0   0   1   0
#12   3 5    10   0   0   0   0   1
#13   4 1    40   1   0   0   0   0
#14   4 2     0   0   0   0   0   0
#15   4 3     0   0   0   0   0   0
#16   4 4     5   0   0   0   1   0
#17   4 5     8   0   0   0   0   1
```

`mydata$t==x & mydata$y.val>0` returns a logical value of `TRUE`/`FALSE` based on condition. The `+` changes those logical values to 1/0 respectively. (Try `+c(FALSE, TRUE)`). It avoids using `ifelse` i.e `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)`.

Comment: @Uddin Updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach based on multiplying a model matrix by the logical `y.val > 0`.

```
df <- cbind(mydata[1:3], model.matrix(~ factor(t) + 0, mydata)*(mydata$y.val>0))
```

Which gives:

```
   sub t y.val factor.t.1 factor.t.2 factor.t.3 factor.t.4 factor.t.5
1    1 1    10          1          0          0          0          0
2    1 2    20          0          1          0          0          0
3    1 3    13          0          0          1          0          0
4    2 1     5          1          0          0          0          0
5    2 2     7          0          1          0          0          0
6    2 3     8          0          0          1          0          0
7    2 4     0          0          0          0          0          0
8    3 1    45          1          0          0          0          0
9    3 2    17          0          1          0          0          0
10   3 3    25          0          0          1          0          0
11   3 4    12          0          0          0          1          0
12   3 5    10          0          0          0          0          1
13   4 1    40          1          0          0          0          0
14   4 2     0          0          0          0          0          0
15   4 3     0          0          0          0          0          0
16   4 4     5          0          0          0          1          0
17   4 5     8          0          0          0          0          1
```

To clean up the names you can do:

```
names(df) <- sub("factor.t.", "It", names(df), fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sapply` to compare each `t` for equality against `1:5` and combine this with an `&` of `y.val>0`.

```
within(mydata, It <- +(sapply(1:5, `==`, t) & y.val>0))
#   sub t y.val It.1 It.2 It.3 It.4 It.5
#1    1 1    10    1    0    0    0    0
#2    1 2    20    0    1    0    0    0
#3    1 3    13    0    0    1    0    0
#4    2 1     5    1    0    0    0    0
#5    2 2     7    0    1    0    0    0
#6    2 3     8    0    0    1    0    0
#7    2 4     0    0    0    0    0    0
#8    3 1    45    1    0    0    0    0
#9    3 2    17    0    1    0    0    0
#10   3 3    25    0    0    1    0    0
#11   3 4    12    0    0    0    1    0
#12   3 5    10    0    0    0    0    1
#13   4 1    40    1    0    0    0    0
#14   4 2     0    0    0    0    0    0
#15   4 3     0    0    0    0    0    0
#16   4 4     5    0    0    0    1    0
#17   4 5     8    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidyverse solution, using `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0("It", t),
         y_test = as.integer(y.val > 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(sub, t, y.val),
              names_from = new_col,
              values_from = y_test,
              values_fill = list(y_test = 0))

     sub     t y.val   It1   It2   It3   It4   It5
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1    10     1     0     0     0     0
 2     1     2    20     0     1     0     0     0
 3     1     3    13     0     0     1     0     0
 4     2     1     5     1     0     0     0     0
 5     2     2     7     0     1     0     0     0
 6     2     3     8     0     0     1     0     0
 7     2     4     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8     3     1    45     1     0     0     0     0
 9     3     2    17     0     1     0     0     0
10     3     3    25     0     0     1     0     0
11     3     4    12     0     0     0     1     0
12     3     5    10     0     0     0     0     1
13     4     1    40     1     0     0     0     0
14     4     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
15     4     3     0     0     0     0     0     0
16     4     4     5     0     0     0     1     0
17     4     5     8     0     0     0     0     1
```

Explanation:

- Make two columns, `new_col` (new column names with "It") and `y_test` (`y.val` > 0).
- Pivot `new_col` values into column names.
- Fill in the `NA` values with zeros.

Answer (score 2):

One `purrr` and `dplyr` option could be:

```
map_dfc(.x = 1:5,
        ~ mydata %>%
         mutate(!!paste0("It", .x) := as.integer(t == .x & y.val > 0)) %>%
         select(starts_with("It"))) %>%
 bind_cols(mydata)

   It1 It2 It3 It4 It5 sub t y.val
1    1   0   0   0   0   1 1    10
2    0   1   0   0   0   1 2    20
3    0   0   1   0   0   1 3    13
4    1   0   0   0   0   2 1     5
5    0   1   0   0   0   2 2     7
6    0   0   1   0   0   2 3     8
7    0   0   0   0   0   2 4     0
8    1   0   0   0   0   3 1    45
9    0   1   0   0   0   3 2    17
10   0   0   1   0   0   3 3    25
11   0   0   0   1   0   3 4    12
12   0   0   0   0   1   3 5    10
13   1   0   0   0   0   4 1    40
14   0   0   0   0   0   4 2     0
15   0   0   0   0   0   4 3     0
16   0   0   0   1   0   4 4     5
17   0   0   0   0   1   4 5     8
```

Or if you want to perform it dynamically according the range in t column:

```
map_dfc(.x = reduce(as.list(range(mydata$t)), `:`),
        ~ mydata %>%
         mutate(!!paste0("It", .x) := as.integer(t == .x & y.val > 0)) %>%
         select(starts_with("It"))) %>%
 bind_cols(mydata)
```